# Lighting issues with added shapes

Tags: modeling, light

Okay, so I'm fairly new to blender and decided to a larger project to get a feel for the program. I was creating a model for a dragon like creature, but, there have been some strange lighting errors. They appear on the seams of where I had to add a new shape to the mesh within edit mode. The shapes them selves are a lighter white color in edit mode. It also gets worse when rendered[image: The mesh is flat but shows a shadow line]
Well, if you have any ideas please send them my way. 
P.S.(I would have send more images, but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Does `W` > *Remove Doubles* in edit mode solve anything?

Comment: Okay, it took an ungodly amount of time and point editing, but I figured out a fix.  I had to extrude each face that had the shadow in order to get rid of it. Thanks for the input though. =)

Comment: It seems to me that the different parts of your mesh are not connected, If you are using a subsurf modifier or just smooth shading the smoothing will end at the edges of a section of the mesh and not continue unless the adjacent faces are connected by common vertices. In edit mode select one vertex and then press Ctrl+ L to select linked vertices, that will let you see which sections are not connected. The easiest solution is  using Remove Doubles (if you have overlapping vertices) else you are going to need to connect them manually.

Comment: @cegaton I tired that and just removing after selecting everything and removing doubles but that phantom shadow is not effected. The extrude solution sort of works, but doesn't look great so I'll probably just redo the neck.